# Inject External JS into iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm making a basic editing system.  For this I have an iFrame on the page, and I am wanting to inject javascript into it.  I've tried a few different methods and have come to a method which works (injecting inline script), ideally I don't want to do it this way, I want to inject an external script file.  The current code I have is:

```
function addScript(src, myscript2) {
    var iFrameHead = window.frames["main_iframe"].document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];        
    var myscript = document.createElement('script');
    myscript.type = 'text/javascript';
    myscript.src = src;
    iFrameHead.appendChild(myscript);
    iFrameHead.innerHTML = iFrameHead.innerHTML + myscript2;
}
addScript("js/jquery-3.1.1.js", "<scr" + "ipt>function frame_hover(e) {e.preventDefault();console.log('hover enter ', $(e.target));}function frame_drop(e) {e.preventDefault();console.log('drop ', $(e.target));}console.log('iframe loaded and script loaded');</scr" + "ipt>");
```

This is working, the jQuery file is working, as is the inline script that's injected.

I want it to work like this:

```
tion injectJS() {
function addScript(src) {
    var iFrameHead = window.frames["main_iframe"].document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];        
    var myscript = document.createElement('script');
    myscript.type = 'text/javascript';
    myscript.src = src;
    iFrameHead.appendChild(myscript);
}
addScript("js/jquery-3.1.1.js");
addScript("js/frame_script.js");
```

}

Although when doing it this way, I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: frame_hover is not defined at HTMLBodyElement.ondragenter`

frame_hover is called from:

```
$('#main_iframe').contents().find('body')
                            .attr('ondragenter', 'frame_hover(event)');
```

the content of frame_script.js is:

```
function frame_hover(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('hover enter ', $(e.target));
}
function frame_drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('drop ', $(e.target));
}
console.log('iframe loaded and script loaded');
```

What really doesn't make sense to me with this, is that jQuery works injecting it this way, that's loaded exactly the same way as the external file `frame_script.js` is loaded, why is it not seeing the file?!

Comment: On which body have you set "HTMLBodyElement.ondragenter"? It is defined in the iframe's, not its parent.

Comment: @Joschi edited question to detail this.

Comment: @Geoff have you tried with like this `addScript("http://example.com/js/jquery-3.1.1.js")` ?

Comment: @Killuminati yes I've just edited the links for posting on here, they are both actually the full links.

Comment: Still hard to say, your script does not run in my chrome browser at all. Can you try to get the iframe document (after all content, even iframe, loaded, in parent window.load!) using `document.getElementById('main_iframe').contentWindow.document` and create the script node you insert from this?